# How to delete/remove an entire row in an Excel (XLS) file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I created an XLS file with LibreOffice and I want to manipulate it with IntelliJ (using Java 20 and Apache POI 5.2.3). In the else statement (when checkbox4 is not selected) I want a particular row to be deleted entirely.

Here is the part of the code:

```
if (box4.isSelected()) {
    Row rowSales = sheet.getRow(30);
    Cell cell4 = rowSales.getCell(0); //getting cell at row 31 - column A
    cell4.setCellValue(sales); //setting a given value
} else {
    Row rowSales = sheet.getRow(30);
    sheet.removeRow(rowSales);
}
```

The edited Excel sheet is then exported in a new Excel file, where row 31 of the file is blank, but not removed.

By using the "removeRow" command, the row is being left blank, rather than deleted/removed.

I've already tried the alternative of the "shiftRows" command where all the rows are being moved one position to the top, but that doesn't suit me since it messes up the format (each row has a particular format).

Answer (score 1):

[Sheet.removeRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#removeRow-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row-) is named confusing. It only removes all cell definitions in given row and the row definition itself from the sheet. So `Row rowSales = sheet.getRow(30); sheet.removeRow(rowSales);` removes all definitions of row 31 from sheet. But nevertheless the previous row definition in sheet is the one of row 30 and the following row definition is the one of row 32. Thus, if sheet gets rendered, then row 30 gets rendered, then nothing defined gets rendered as row 31 and then row 32 gets rendered.

If row 31 shall disappear, then rows 32 up to last row in sheet must be shifted up one row. That's what [Sheet.shiftRows](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ShiftRows) is for.

If `Sheet.shiftRows` not works for you, then this is another question and needs another SO Question too providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).